# Прошу помочь разобраться с симлинками (php)

Tags: symlinks, php

Всем Вам доброго здравия, господа. Хочу обратиться за помощью к знающим. На днях в проекте столкнулся вот с такой штукой:

// Ввод в курс дела
Я пишу генератор сайтов и при нажатии на кнопочку "Создать сайт" происходит много всего интересного И необходимо создать каталог для сайта в котором будет несколько папочек и "как бы" папочек (символические ссылки на содержимое каталога репозитория), нужно это для избежания копирования одних и тех же файлов каждый раз при создании сайта.

Обстановка в тылу следующая.
Структура каталогов вот такая:

```
htdocs
|
|-- repository
| |-- admin
| |-- core
| |-- modules
| |-- classes
|
|-- sites
| |--site_1
| |--...
| |--site_n
|
|--..
```

Нужно сделать ссылки (симлинки) так чтоб содержимое каталога htdocs/repository было доступно из htdocs/sites/site_i
Я погуглил, но так что-то ничего внятного и не нашел про симлинки. Пишут про то, что в винде такой роскоши нет. Я понял лишь то, что это что-то вроде ярлыков в винде. (Больше ничего про симлинки не знаю.. как и про unix-системы в целом, может кто-то кинет в меня камень, но я если не фанат, то большой поклонник MS) Ребят, подскажите как быть. Какую строчку и куда записать? Пишу на php.

Comment: Получается тебе надо эмулировать симлинки в системе "Форточки"?

Comment: угу. что-то вроде того. я читал, что тут симлинки нужны. работаю с удаленным сервером Apache/2.2.17 (FreeBSD). php 5.3.6 самая последняя вообщем. дело в том что я не знаю как создавать эти симлинки и как с ними работать. 
  а у себя разработку веду на "Форточках"=)

Comment: Вопрос решен. Кубеев Арман спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Симлинки представляют собой много более обычных виндузовых ярлыков. Для обычной программы, как и скрипта симлинки на файлы и папки ведут себя почти так же как и обычные файлы и папки. Если на сервере стоит UNIX-подобная система, то можно смело пользоваться функцией

```
bool symlink ( string $target , string $link )
```

[Пруфлинк](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.symlink.php). Вместо target посылаете действительное расположение папки, а вместо link путь к симлинку в папке пользователя. В системе Windows никакие симлинки не работают. Так что потестить данную функцию на домашнем компьютере не удастся.

Comment: В винде есть хардлинки. <a href=http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D1%91%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0>Proof</href> А вместо symlink'ов можно использовать <a href=http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point>junction</href>